# Fitting a lognormal or poisson distribution

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution, poisson, model-fitting

I have a vector of 1096 numbers, the daily average concentration of NOx measured in 3 years in a measurement station.
You can observe the type of distribution in the image:

[image: Histogram of NOx concentration]

I used these commands to do the histogram:

```
NOxV<-scan("NOx_Vt15-17.txt")
hist.NOxVt<-hist(NOxV, plot = FALSE, breaks = 24) 
plot(hist.NOxVt, xlab = "[NOx]", ylab = "Frequenze assolute", main = "Istogramma freq. ass. NOx 15-17 Viterbo")
points(hist.NOxVt$mids, hist.NOxVt$counts, col= "red")
```

My professor suggested that I fit the histogram with a Poisson distribution - paying attention to the transition: discrete -> continuous (I don't know what that means)- or with a "Lognormal" distribution.

I tried to do the Poisson fit, with some command lines that she gave us at lesson, but R gave me an error after having executed the last code line of the following:

```
  my_poisson = function(params, x){
      exp(-params)*params^x/factorial(x)
  }
    
  y<-hist.NOxVt$counts/1096;
  x<-hist.NOxVt$mids;
  z <- nls( y ~ exp(-a)*a^x/factorial(x), start=list(a=1) )
```

> Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) :
> Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
> In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"

After this problem I couldn't solve (even searching similar problems on the internet) I decided to fit the distribution with a Lognormal, but I have no idea how to do it, because the professor did not explain it to us, and I still don't have enough R experience to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a built-in function `fitdistr` in the `MASS` package that comes with R:

Generating a data example to look at (eyeballing parameters to get something similar to your picture):

```
set.seed(101)
z <- rlnorm(1096,meanlog=4.5,sdlog=0.8)
```

Fit (on statistical grounds I wouldn't recommend a Poisson fit - it might be possible to adapt a discrete distribution such as Poisson (or better, negative binomial) to fit such continuous data, but log-Normal or Gamma distributions are more natural choices.

```
library(MASS)
f1 <- fitdistr(z,"lognormal")
f2 <- fitdistr(z,"Gamma")
```

The `f1` and `f2` objects, when printed, give the estimated coefficients (`meanlog` and `sdlog` for log-Normal, `shape` and `rate` for Gamma) and standard errors of the coefficients.

Draw a picture (on the density scale, not the count scale): red is log-Normal, blue is Gamma (in this case log-Normal fits better because that's how I generated the "data" in the first place). [The `with(as.list(coef(...))` stuff is some R fanciness to allow the use of the *names* of the coefficients (`meanlog`, `sdlog` etc.) in the subsequent R code.]

```
hist(z,col="gray",breaks=50,freq=FALSE)
with(as.list(coef(f1)),
     curve(dlnorm(x,meanlog,sdlog),
           add=TRUE,col="red",lwd=2))
with(as.list(coef(f2)),
     curve(dgamma(x,shape=shape,rate=rate),
           add=TRUE,col="blue",lwd=2))
```

[image]